# LM338, which capacitors to use

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, voltage-regulator

Do you have to place the input and output capacitors on LOAD basis or the capacitors specified in the datasheet.
I have a linear power supply that supplies 16 Volts with no load.
The maximum load I want to apply to this regulator would be less than 2A and maximum Voltage, 9 Volts.
I just need to know what values of capacitors to use. My supply does have a 4700uF filter capacitor but it is around 2 feet away. I want to make this regulator in separate box.

Comment: The datasheet is pretty clear, go with what it recommends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there are instances where there will be no load OR if load is disconnected, consider the following.

> A 250-Ω feedback resistor between OUTPUT and ADJUST consumes the worst
>   case minimum load current of 5 mA

Regarding the capacitor, go with the datasheet spec. atleast for input voltage:

> CIN: 0.1 μF of input capacitance helps filter out unwanted noise,
>   especially if the regulator is located far from the power supply
>   filter capacitors.

Output capacitor is optional:

> COUT: The regulator is stable without any output capacitance, but
>   adding a 1-μF capacitor improves the transient response.
>
> certain values of external capacitance can cause excessive ringing.
>   This occurs with values between 500 pF and 5000 pF. A 1-μF solid
>   tantalum (or 25-μF aluminum electrolytic) on the output swamps this
>   effect and insures stability.

[image]

Finally, 14 W of heat is dissipated, which is okay for the device. But, consider it wisely.

Comment: As this is a NPN pass element design, ceramics could very probably be used here with no ill effects.